# trying to start a tomcat from eclipse and it failed to find index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

type Status report

message /mydirectory/index.jsp

description The requested resource (/mydirectory/index.jsp) is not available.

What could be the issue?

Here is the log file:

Jul 28, 2009 6:16:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Testing' did not find a matching property.
Jul 28, 2009 6:16:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Sun\SDK\bin
Jul 28, 2009 6:16:25 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 28, 2009 6:16:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 447 ms
Jul 28, 2009 6:16:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 28, 2009 6:16:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse 3.4 or 3.5 -- look at the Servers view in Eclipse. Against your server, you should see "Started" and "Synchronized". If it tells you to restart or republish, right-click on your server and do so.

Deploy your file again (you can drag your index.jsp file on to the server). Does it start this time?

If not, something could be wrong with your web.xml. Open the Console view and look at the server log -- do you notice any exceptions etc? You will need to resolve those.

Comment: To rule out any Tomcat configuration/installation issues, could you try creating a new Dynamic Web Project, add a JSP file to it, and deploy that on Tomcat and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your server plug-in configuration:
When Tomcat within Eclipse publishes you Dynamic Web Project, all embedded tomcat useful files (conf, code, work) are stored in this following location:

```
<path_to_workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp[0-9]
```

Check the deployment architecture, if you need more help regarding tomcat files architecture, see [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/introduction.html)